# Using Team Foundation Server for QA / Testing

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have been playing around with TFS (Team Foundation Server) on my visual studio 2012.

I went to `Work Items` and I saw `My Bugs`,`My Tasks`,`My Test Cases`.

All are empty at the moment. I want to know how can I set up a test case in TFS > Work Items > My Test Cases? Or Add Bugs in My Bugs.

I also read somewhere - Cant remember now - You can actually edit the my test case screen to some of your own test case criteria.

Anyone know's about this or where I can start?

Answer (score 0):

These are just Queries that run over all the work items. Users with appropriate permissions can edit them, but the changes will apply to the whole team.

You can copy and paste them from Shared Queries into My Queries and work on them.

The way they work is looking for any work item assigned to the viewer of the query (using a variable called @Me in the filter) that has the Bug / Task / Test Case Work Item type and is not closed.

Here's an example of "My Tasks" from my MSF Agile Project:
[image]

When you view the results, there is button in the top right called "Edit Query" to get this view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new bugs , or other work items by clicking on the team menu. You can then create new work items and assign them to yourself or other members of your team